# Проблема с QTcpSocket - нельзя считать после записи

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, qtcpsocket

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть проект, в котором используется QTcpSocket и выглядит он в общем случае вот так:

```
QTcpSocket *Q_socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
Q_socket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);
if (Q_socket == NULL)
{
    return error ;// сокет не открылся
}
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < send_sequence_length; cnt++) //
{
     //заполняем массив на отправку
     data_send[to_send_counter] = to_send_array[cnt];
     to_send_counter++;
     //когда он заполнился
     if (to_send_counter == 32) //Отсылаем по 32
     {
     send_error = Q_socket->write((char*) &data_send, 32*sizeof(ToSend));
     if (send_error == -1)
        {
            return error = -5; //ошибка приёма/передачи
        }
        to_send_counter = 0;
     }
}
RecData = Q_socket->readAll();
Q_socket->close();
Q_socket->waitForDisconnected();
```

Проблема в том, что при считывании он ничего не возвращает - RecData остается пустой. При постановке breakpoint'а он досылает лишь малое количество пакетов, а после продолжения работы программы оставшиеся и ничего не возвращает при чтении. При этом все пакеты доходят до адресата, это подтверждается на приёмной стороне. Каким образом следует считывать данные, с какой задержкой, или вообще открыть для этого другой сокет?

Comment: readAll прочитает все доступные в буфере данные. Если данные ещё не добежали, то их эта функция не прочитает.  Почему? а она просто не знает, сколько читать. Поэтому, нужно организовывать цикл и и читать ровно столько, сколько нужно, передавая размер в первых байтах или читая до конца строки.

Comment: @KoVadim Я делал и через ready_read. Он проскакивал операции и ничего не возвращал даже при больших задержках

Comment: лучше подписаться на сигнал readyRead и там все получать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ни при каком сигнале данные не приходят от удаленного сервера. WireShark их не видит, но это распространенная проблема, я читал статьи про акулью слепоту касательно QTшных сокетов. Может быть стоит давать ему sleep или иную задержку, чтоб успевал обрабатывать и принимать?

Comment: Нет у wireshark'a слепоты на Qt сокеты. Это такие же сокеты, как и все остальные. Другое дело, что wireshark под виндой не видит пакеты на локалхост, но это особенности винды. Но если пакеты не приходят от удаленного сервера, то может просто он их не присылает?

Comment: Да, он действительно их не присылает. Но все-таки как тогда объяснить то, что он не отрабатывает посылку всех пакетов на сервер до breakpoint'а, стоящего на close, и досылает их потом?

Comment: Если Ваше приложение остановленно на брекпоинте, то оно не может слать ничего в сеть. Оно остановленно. Также нужно помнить, что сеть не резиновая и туда много запихнуть нельзя. Вполне возможно, что у Вас слабое соединение, а данных много.

Comment: Соединение точка-точка. У меня есть приложение такого же характера, но написано на C#. Там оно отсылает данные до брейкпоинта стоящего на socket.close() и после него ничего не шлет

Comment: Скорее всего загвоздка в том, что приложение на шарпе использует блокирующие сокеты, а Qt приложение - неблокирующие. А логика работы с ними различная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа с сокетами в Qt асинхронная. Бесполезно пытаться отправлять данные и ожидать, что тут же придёт ответ, блокируя при этом диспетчер событий, который в свою очередь включается через `QCoreApplication::exec()`.

Методы `QAbstractSocket::waitForBytesWritten()` и `QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead()`, хотя и реализуют блокирующие вызовы, тем не менее в Windows могут вести себя некорректно, о чём честно предупреждается в справке.

Единственным надёжным способом дождаться уведомления от сокета о прибытии новой порции данных является подключение к сигналу `QIODevice::readyRead()`. Слово "порция" является ключевым и подразумевает, что не все данные, которые были отправлены передающей стороной, обязательно уже получены и готовы к чтению.

Итого, принципиальными моментами являются:

1. создание объекта сокета;
2. подключение к удалённому серверу;
3. отправка данных;
4. уход в ожидание ответа, но не при помощи `sleep`, а именно через активацию обработчика событий;
5. получение ответа по сигналу с обработкой на возможность прихода данных по частям.

Организация соединения и получение данных может быть выполнены, например, так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSharedPointer<QTcpSocket> socket(new QTcpSocket());

    connect(socket.data(), &QTcpSocket::connected, [socket]() {
        connect(socket.data(), &QTcpSocket::readyRead(), [socket]() {
            qDebug() << socket->readAll();
        });

        socket->write("tra-ta-ta");
    });

    socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 9999);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень доходчиво объяснили. Очень жаль, конечно, что все не так просто, как в C++ или в C#, не хотелось плодить ещё сигналы-слоты, но ваше решение помогло.

Comment: @ТарасКолеско, пожалуйста. В Qt приоритетен GUI, и потому асинхронности уделяется основное внимание, чтобы не "морозить" интерфейс пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает кармы, чтобы написать в комментарий. Вроде можно сделать задержку через QEventLoop. Например, что-то наподобие:

```
QEventLoop wait;
connect (Q_socket, SIGNAL(finished()), &wait, SLOT(quit()));
QTimer::singleShot(10000, &wait, SLOT(quit()));
wait.exec();
```